# Does SearchResultCollection's GetDirectoryEntry have to query ActiveDirectory again? [DirectoryServices/.net]

Tags: .net, performance, active-directory, directoryservices

When using the FindAll() method of the DirectorySearcher in .net, does the GetDirectoryEntry() method of the SearchResultCollection require another trip to Active Directory? e.g....

```
Dim src As SearchResultCollection
Dim ds As New DirectorySearcher
' code to setup DirectorySearcher


' go to Active Directory and fill collection with results
src = ds.FindAll()

'...later on in code or whatever
' does the next line of code require another trip to Active Directory?
Dim de As DirectoryEntry = src.item(0).GetDirectoryEntry()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation it will requery AD to get the directory entry.

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.searchresult.getdirectoryentry.aspx)

> Use GetDirectoryEntry when you want to
> look at the live entry instead of the
> entry that was returned through
> DirectorySearcher, or when you want to
> invoke a method on the object that was
> returned.
>
> Note:
> Calling GetDirectoryEntry on each SearchResult returned through DirectorySearcher can be slow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will go back to AD and get the whole DirectoryEntry object.

If you want to avoid this (and you should, whenever possible), specify those properties you really need on your `DirectorySearcher` using the `PropertiesToLoad` collection, and then inspect the `SearchResult.Properties` for those values - those will be returned with the search and do not require yet another roundtrip to the Active Directory.

Marc